# Changing organization of data so that each observation represents a new variable (I tried)

Tags: stata, data-analysis, data-management

I am working in Stata with a dataset on electric vehicle charging stations. Variables include

`station_name` name of charging station

`review_text` all of the customer reviews for a specific station delimited by `}{`

`num_reviews` number of customer reviews.

I'm trying to make a new file where each observation represents one customer review in a new variable `customer_review` and another variable `station_id` has the name of the corresponding station. So, if the original dataset had 100 observations (one per station) with 5 reviews each, the new file should have 500 observations.

How can I do this? I would include some code I have tried but I have no idea how to start.

Comment: The answer looks good to me. Please accept it or explain why it's not quite what you want.

Comment: @NickCox how do I accept it?

Comment: You should see a tick box left of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data look like this:

```
       station              reviews   n  
  1.         1   {good}{bad}{great}   3  
  2.         2    {poor}{excellent}   2
```

Then the following:

```
split(reviews), parse(}{)
drop reviews n
reshape long reviews, i(station) j(review_num)
drop if reviews==""
replace reviews = subinstr(reviews, "}","",.)
replace reviews = subinstr(reviews, "{","",.)
```

will produce:

```
       station   review~m     reviews  
  1.         1          1        good  
  2.         1          2         bad  
  3.         1          3       great  
  4.         2          1        poor  
  5.         2          2   excellent
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This is exactly what I needed